# Library to connect Java Client to a nodejs sockjs server?

Tags: java, websocket

Im trying to connect from a Java client i am writing to my nodejs sockjs server.

The sockjs server is just a simple echo server, taken from the examples on git:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var sockjs = require('sockjs');
    var node_static = require('node-static');

    // 1. Echo sockjs server
    var sockjs_opts = {sockjs_url: "http://cdn.sockjs.org/sockjs-0.3.min.js"};

    var sockjs_echo = sockjs.createServer(sockjs_opts);
    sockjs_echo.on('connection', function(conn) {
        conn.on('data', function(message) {
            conn.write(message);
        });
    });

    // 2. Static files server
    var static_directory = new node_static.Server(__dirname);

    // 3. Usual http stuff
    var server = http.createServer();
    server.addListener('request', function(req, res) {
        static_directory.serve(req, res);
    });
    server.addListener('upgrade', function(req,res){
        res.end();
    });

    sockjs_echo.installHandlers(server, {prefix:'/echo'});

    console.log(' [*] Listening on 0.0.0.0:8080' );
    server.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0');
```

Now i've tried to connect from my Java client with the following:

```
 public static void connect() throws Exception {
    final WebSocket ws = new WebSocket();
    ws.addWebSocketListener(
          new WebSocketAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void onMessage(WebSocketEvent messageEvent) {
         System.out.println("Received Event Data: " + messageEvent.getData());
         // let's close the open connection...
         try {
             ws.close();
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
     @Override
     public void onOpen(WebSocketEvent openEvent) {
         System.out.println("Connection to Server is up!");
          // we are able to talk to the WebSocket gateway
         try {
             ws.send("Hey, server!");
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
            }
          }
        );
        ws.connect(new URI("ws://server.hello.com:8080/echo/websocket"));
    }
```

The error i am getting when my java client tried to connect is:

> com.kaazing.gateway.client.html5.impl.bridge.BridgeUtil
>   initCrossOriginProxy WARNING: Unable to connect: the Gateway may not
>   be running, a network route may be unavailable, or the Gateway may not
>   be configured properly

Any ideas what could be wrong?